# UglifyJs Unexpected token: operator (>)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

Свежий Rails 5.1, поверх которого развернут Vuex паттерн.

Падает компиляция и в тексте ошибки указывает на эту строку (по середине):

```
const getters = {
    statisticsArchive: state => state.statistics.archive
}
```

Судя по всему оператор `>` из заголовка ошибки взят из оператора `=>`.

По одноименным ссылкам из гугла ничего не нашел. Выполнял команду `yarn upgrade --latest` для получения всего самого актуального. Не могу понять в чем дело.

```
ERROR in public/home-ceeb391e69dad354d919.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: operator (>) [./app/javascript/stores/public/modules/home/index.js:41,21][public/home-ceeb391e69dad354d919.js:12853,28]
```

Comment: А какой UglifyJS используется и какой версии?

Comment: @D-side в `webpack@^3.5.5` прописан `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin "^0.4.6"`. Также ниже прописано: https://pastebin.com/VEipPLJs - это я взял из yarn.lock файла.

Comment: @D-side я пробовал добавлять в файл package.json `uglify-es`. Этот пакет ставился рядом со второй версией и автоматически брал `uglify-js` третьей версии. Но это никак не помогло.

Comment: Вероятно, потому что `uglifyjs-webpack-plugin` по-прежнему пользуется uglify-js, а не uglify-es. Но проблему, я смотрю, вы установили: что UglifyJS не умеет ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте в корне файл *.babelrc* с этим содержимым:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": "> 1%",
        "uglify": true
      },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }]
  ]
}
```